# Replacing $1 value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 table columns with the following data:

```
[item_name]
Free inodes on $1

[item_key]
vfs.fs.inode[/home,pfree]
```

I would like to write a select statement that places /home where the $1 is so that I have the following returned:

```
Free inodes on /home
```

I have tried a bunch of different searches on Google but I'm not sure how I need to word this to get a useful result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function to do the replacement in the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT REPLACE([item_name], '$1', '/home') FROM [table_name]
```

Now, as you mentioned in your comments, the "/home" could actually be one of several different paths. In that case, the solution becomes more tricky. What I've done below is written a query that takes a substring of the key using the first location of the '[' character and going until it finds a ',' character.

```
SELECT
REPLACE(
    [item_name],
    '$1',
    SUBSTRING(
        [item_key],
        CHARINDEX(
            '[',
            [item_key]
        ) + 1,
        CHARINDEX(
            ',',
            [item_key],
            CHARINDEX(
                '[', [item_key]
            )
        ) - CHARINDEX(
                '[', [item_key]
            ) - 1
        )
    )
    FROM [table_name]
```

Comment: Thanks John but the problem is that /home could be /usr or /boot (or a number of other values).

Comment: @thestepafter - I've edited my answer to take that into account for you.

Comment: If there is no comma before the "[", your answer can be much shorter. However, you may want to check if the key value format first  to avoid substring errors.